# Always getting kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure, even after changing trust settings in Keychain Access

Tags: macos, certificate, keychain, security-framework

When calling `SecTrustEvaluateWithError()` on my `SecTrustRef` object, the API always returns `kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure`. According to header file, this means:

> Indicates a trust policy failure which can be overridden by the user. This value may be returned by the `SecTrustEvaluate` function but not stored as part of the user trust settings.

Being overridable, I changed the trust settings for the untrusted certificate using `Keychain Access` app like so:

[image]

Yet this seems to make no difference, the result is still `kSecTrustResultRecoverableTrustFailure`, so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the problem was caused by calling `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates()`, which I used to add own CA certificates before calling `SecTrustEvaluateWithError()`.

The meanwhile deprecated function `SecTrustEvaluate()` contains an important note in the documentation:

> As an exception, if your app has previously called `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates`, **the user-specified trust settings are ignored**, and the certificate’s chain must contain one of the specified anchor certificates.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/1394363-sectrustevaluate

While this note is missing in the `SecTrustEvaluateWithError()` documentation, it also applies to  this function as well as to `SecTrustEvaluateAsyncWithError()`. If I make sure that `SecTrustSetAnchorCertificates()` is never called, then the user override works as expected (with that override, the cert is considered trusted by the system, without it isn't, which is expected behavior).